# Not able to process big file inside a zip file using ZipInputStream

Tags: java, zip

I am having a below mentioned java class which extracts a zip, and one by one convert its content to string and print to console.

Problem is, when the file present inside the zip is big ~80KB. Entire content is not getting displayed (only 3/4 of the data is getting converted to string and displayed in console).

 Secondly below mentioned code is introducing null/space in between and also if the file size is small ~1KB

what is wrong in below mentioned code.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    final int BUFFER = 1024;
    String fName = "c:\\DOC00001.zip";
    ZipInputStream zinstream = new ZipInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(fName));
    ZipEntry zentry = zinstream.getNextEntry();

    while (zentry != null) {            
    byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while ((zinstream.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
        out.write(data);
    }       
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    IOUtils.copy(is, writer, "UTF-8");
    String response = writer.toString();
    System.out.println(response);
    zentry = zinstream.getNextEntry();
    }
    zinstream.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `read` method is not guaranteed to read a full buffer; the number of bytes that have been read is returned. The correct way to extract data from a zip file, or any `InputStream` in general, would be:

```
byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER];
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = zinstream.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
    out.write(data, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Or, since you are already using `IOUtils`,

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
IOUtils.copy(zinstream, out);
```

Or, given that you write to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` only to later write to a String, you can skip the `ByteArrayOutputStream` entirely:

```
while (zentry != null) {
  StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
  IOUtils.copy(zinstream, writer, "UTF-8");
  String response = writer.toString();
  System.out.println(response);
  zentry = zinstream.getNextEntry();
}
```